# how to copy & paste the data from one column to another between two sheets of excel workbook...without overwriting the destination column content..?

Tags: vba, excel

how to copy & paste the data from one column to another between two sheets of excel workbook ... without overwriting the destination column content?

I am using below code to copy & paste but every time I run it it is overwriting the existed content. I want to be pasted from next row of the column.

```
Sub DirectCopySample()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Updating Sheet").Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G")
    Sheets("Updating Sheet").Range("B:B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F")
    Sheets("Updating Sheet").Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Step 1: find out how much data is in your copy column (how many rows to paste). Step 2: found out how much data is in your paste column (how many rows already have data). Step 3: Paste from the exact range to the exact range. ie: Sheets("Updating Sheet").Range("A1:A500").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A101:A600")

Comment: yeah, you are correct but i don't want to specify destination range like "A101:A600", it has to take the below row which is blank after the data.

Comment: You misunderstand - see @Zak's solution below, which finds the last row of data and then uses that info to find out what the range actually is (you don't actually type "A101:A600", the code determines what the references should actually be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Grade 'Eh' Bacon outlined the correct process in his or her comment.

The crux of the issue is finding the size of the ranges you are copying from and pasting to. My current favorite method of doing so is the code snippet below:

```
copyLastrow = Sheets("Updating Sheet").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

That will find the last non-empty row in your worksheet. So if for some reason column A has 100 rows, B has 200 rows, and C has 300 rows it will return 300 as the last row.

On the paste side of things, you could use the same method and add 1 to it so you paste into the first empty row, but if the columns have different numbers of rows you will end up with many blank rows in the shorter columns before your data is pasted at the bottom.

A work around this is the following code:

```
 pasteLastrowG = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

This will start at the bottom of column G and head up until it hits a row with data in it and then add 1 so that you are pasting into the first blank row of the column. You could then create variables for columns H and I that do the same thing.

Putting it all together your code would look something like this in the end:

```
copyLastrow = Sheets("Updating Sheet").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

pasteLastrowG = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'pasteLastrowH ...
'pasteLastrowI ...

Sheets("Updating Sheet").Range("A2:A" & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & pasteLastrowG)
'Copy and paste B code here
'Copy and paste C code here
```

Comment: It's working fine @Grade 'Eh' Ba... thank you so much. It's working perfect as I expected.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy the entire column. Copy a specific 1-cell-wide range of X rows (where X is your data) and define all your variables based on the current size of the data. For instance if you want to copy column A from sheet1 to the end of column B in sheet2.

```
Sub CopyColumn()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Set wsCopy = Sheets("<Sheet Name>")

Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
Set wsPaste = sheets("<Sheet Name>")

'/ Much better to make your worksheets variables and then reference those

Dim lngFirstRow As Long
Dim lngFinalRow As Long

Dim lngCopyColumn As Long
Dim lngPasteColumn As Long

Dim rngCopy As Range
Dim rngPasteCell As Range

    lngCopyColumn = 1 '/ ("A" Column)
    lngDestinationColumn = 2 '/ ("B" Column)

    wsCopy.Activate

        lngFirstRow = 1
        lngFinalRow = Cells(1048576, lngCopyColumn).End(xlUp).Row 
        '/ Starts at the bottom of the sheet, stops at the first cell with data in it, returns that cell's row

        Set rngCopy = Range(Cells(lngFirstRow, lngCopyColumn), Cells(lngFinalRow, lngCopyColumn))
            '/ Defines the range between those 2 cells
            rngCopy.copy

    wsPaste.Activate

        lngFinalRow = Cells(1048576, lngPasteColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngpaste = Cells(lngFinalRow + 1, lngPasteColumn)
        '/ Pastes to the row 1 cell below the last filed cell in Column B
        rngpaste.Paste

End Sub
```